# Read from XML file using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-ise

I'm finding it hard to figure out a way to retrieve content from XML file. Below is how my xml file looks like. 
I'm trying to retrieve the complete 'nlog' node. Please help.

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
        <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, ..."/>
 </configSections>
  <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <variable name="LoggingDirectory" value="D:/Logging/"/>
      <include file="${LoggingDirectory}Config/Framework.nlog.xml"/>
  </nlog>
 </configuration>
```

here is what I have tried so far:

```
$nlogConfigFile = 'D:\machine.config.nlog.xml'
$nlogConfigXml = new-object xml
$nlogConfigXml.Load($nlogConfigFile);
$nlogConfigXml.PreserveWhitespace = $true
```

I have used the "Get-XmlNode" function provided in this blog http://blog.danskingdom.com/powershell-functions-to-get-an-xml-node-and-get-and-set-an-xml-elements-value-even-when-the-element-does-not-already-exist/

```
Get-XmlNode -XmlDocument $nlogConfigXml -NodePath "configuration.configSections.section[@name='nlog']"     ## works OK
Get-XmlNode -XmlDocument $nlogConfigXml -NodePath "configuration.nlog"   ## does NOT work
```

I have also tried "Select-Xml" , .SelectSingleNode commands but none of them seem to work. 
Please let me know if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
$nlogConfigXml = [xml]$(gc "D:\machine.config.nlog.xml")
```

Then you can navigate `$nlogConfigXml` using object notation.

For example, doing this:

```
$nlogConfigXml.configuration.nlog.variable.name
```

...outputs this:

```
LoggingDirectory
```

Comment: Hi How do I access an element by attribute using this model ? For example: retrieve the section with name= 'nlog' ?

Comment: @CrazyFrog - I've added an example.

Comment: For Powershell noobs (I'm currently one of them) - `gc` is short for `Get-Content`, not *garbage collector*.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Select-Xml and XPath. Mind that you need to include namespace info to make it work correctly:

```
$Xml = [xml]@'
<configuration>
<configSections>
        <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, ..."/>
 </configSections>
  <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <variable name="LoggingDirectory" value="D:/Logging/"/>
      <include file="${LoggingDirectory}Config/Framework.nlog.xml"/>
  </nlog>
</configuration>
'@

Select-Xml -Xml $Xml -Namespace @{
    n = "http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
} -XPath //n:nlog
```

Namespace definition (hashtable value) is just copy/paste of `xmlns`.
The name you specify (hashtable key) is the same you later have to use in XPath queries as a prefix for XPath elements (as in example: `n:nlog`)

Answer (score 0):

```
$nlogConfigFile = '.\machine.config.nlog.xml'
[XML]$xmlFileContent = Get-Content $nlogConfigFile
$xmlFileContent.configuration.nlog.variable.name
```

Just a little bit different format from the answer before.

Comment: This doesn't work properly it always have been throwing the error. The answer specified by @enigmitavity was helpful and working as expected.